# Assignment and NOT equal precedences

Tags: c

In the page 17 of **The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition** the writer says that

> The *precedence* of `!=` is higher than that of `=`

So when I want to test it, it's not that way. This is my simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inp;

    while(inp = getchar() != EOF) {
        putchar(inp);
    }
}
```

Which I try to read an input and show it to the user. When I try that, nothing happen and the screen is empty, but when I try this one, everything works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inp;

    while((inp = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(inp);
    }

}
```

What's the matter? I have `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`.

Comment: If the precedence is higher, won't it be interpreted as `inp = (getchar() != EOF)`?

Comment: Please note that `=` does not mean "equal to".  It is the assignment operator.  `==` is "equal to".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's happening is exactly what you're saying, `The precedence of != is higher than that of =`.

That means that `!=` *binds harder* than `=` and

```
while(inp = getchar() != EOF) {
```

is equivalent to;

```
while(inp = (getchar() != EOF)) {
```

That will set `inp` to the bool value of the comparison, not the character value you're looking for.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani They're not supposed to. The way to make it work is to _override_ the precedence with parentheses `(inp = getchar()) != EOF`, exactly like you did with your working example. That assigns inp to the char, _then_  compares the result of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your two conditions are equivalent to:

```
char notEndOfFile = (getchar() != EOF); // notEndOfFile is a boolean
if(!(inp = notEndOfFile))    // inp is now a boolean, not the character input
   break;                    // break if notEndOfFile is false
```

This terminates at the right time, but doesn't assign inp as desired.

and:

```
inp = getchar();     // As desired
if(inp != EOF) break // break if inp is EOF
```

Terminates and assigns inp correctly.