# C boolean value

Tags: c, boolean

As an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382136/equal-and-not-equal-precedences) question,

> What's happening is exactly what you're saying, The precedence of !=
>   is higher than that of =.
>
> That means that != binds harder than = and
>
> while(inp = getchar() != EOF) {
>
> is equivalent to;
>
> while(inp = (getchar() != EOF)) {
>
> That will set inp to the bool value of the comparison, not the
>   character value you're looking for.

this answer is credited as true. But, there is the part of it which makes me confused, the last sentence:

> That will set inp to the bool value of the comparison, not the
>   character value you're looking for.

In here, if inp is set a bool value(which is true I believe), why can't we see the value when we use `putchar(inp)`? Why don't we see 0 or 1 on the screen?

---

Question:

In the page 17 of The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition the writer says that

```
The precedence of != is higher than that of =
```

So when I want to test it, it's not that way. This is my simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inp;

    while(inp = getchar() != EOF) {
        putchar(inp);
    }
}
```

Which I try to read an input and show it to the user. When I try that, nothing happen and the screen is empty, but when I try this one, everything works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int inp;

    while((inp = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(inp);
    }

}
```

What's the matter? I have gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00).

Comment: The characters with value `0` and `1` are not visible on the display. Try `putchar(inp + '0');` or `printf("%02X", inp);`

Comment: It will output the character `SOH` that has the ascii (or other current system locale encoding) value 1 (an unprintable character) Depending on the console you're running, you may get nothing or a garbage character.

Comment: I get     11 when I use     putchar(inp + '0');, with    printf("%02X", inp); option, I get 0101.

Comment: @ErcanOzturk Put a line feed in the format string, `printf("%02X\n", inp);` and you'll probably see it prints '01' (the ascii code of the character) for every iteration.

Comment: Yeah, it prints 01 this time when I use    printf("%02X\n", inp);, when I enter EOF, It prints nothing(just a blank line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In here, if inp is set a bool value(which is true I believe), why can't we see the value when we use putchar(inp)? Why don't we see 0 or 1 on the screen?

Because the character codes 0 and 1 are apparently not printable characters in your system locale. `0` and `'0'` are different.

Comment: Indeed, character `0` is guaranteed to be the nul terminator -- so even if it is "printable" in the sense that printing it makes something happen on the terminal, it's never a letter/number/etc.

Comment: I used    printf("%d", inp);, but It prints 11 not 0 when it is not an EOF, when it is, it prints 1. Is the false value's int equivalent 11, why not 0?

Comment: @ErcanOzturk Why do you assume `EOF` is integer 0? It isn't... Also, you seem to be confusing the return value of `getchar()` with the value of the expression `getchar() != EOF`.

Comment: getchar() != EOF returns a boolean value, anyway, I get the "printable" point here. Thanks @Steve and @H2CO3!

Answer (score 1):

> In here, if inp is set a bool value(which is true I believe), why
>   can't we see the value when we use putchar(inp)? Why don't we see 0 or
>   1 on the screen?

It's not a `'1'` or a `'0'` (integer values `48` and `49` in ASCII). It's an integer value `1` or `0` (`'\1'` or a `'\0'`).

```
printf("%d\n", '0'); /* prints the integer value of '0', followed by newline */
printf("%c\n", '0'); /* prints '0', followed by newline */

printf("%d\n", 0); /* prints '0', followed by newline */
printf("%c\n", 0); /* prints '\0' (null terminator), followed by newline */
```